# Cant seem to read a tmp file via ifstream line by line

Tags: c++, mfc

Just like to know what I am doing wrong. I have a file (file.tmp) that has content of : c:\users\documents\file\folder\myfile.txt. I would like to read the tmp file with this code:

```
    std::ifstream istream(csTempPath);
    std::string s;
    if (istream.is_open()){
            int i = 1;
            while (std::getline(istream, s))
            {
                CString cs;
                cs.Format(L"Reading: %s", s);

                OutputDebugString(cs);
                i++;
            }
            istream.close();
        }
    else{
            OutputDebugString(L"Could not read the temp file.");
    }
```

The output Im getting is this:

```
[4376] Reading: ??
[4376] Reading: ??
```

I expect it to get this: `c:\users\documents\file\folder\myfile.txt` but for some reason I get that,I tried variety of ways but I cant seem to know whats wrong. BTW Im a beginning programmer.

Comment: `CString::Format` expects a `const char *` for `%s`, rather than a `std::string`. You want `s.c_str()`.

Comment: I will give it a go.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe It worked. Just another follow up question, file path that got returned also added "???" at the end "c:\users\documents\file\folder\myfile.txt???" just seem weird. but nevertheless I got the answer.

Comment: Based on that error description and the fact, that @RogerLipscombe's incorrect suggestion appears to work leads me to believe, that your *"file.tmp"* holds UTF-16 encoded content. Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: @IInspectable yes the suggestion sort of work,now when I have multiple line of text in the file.tmp file it returns the first line correctly but the next text and the rest returns "???????", I do suspect it something to do with encoding,I wrote the file.tmp using wofstream and feed it with cstringw, now reading it back gives me weird output..

Comment: `wofstream` (on Windows) writes UTF-16 encoded data. The code you posted in the question works (somewhat) for the first line, by reading a UTF-16 encoded string into a `basic_string<char>` (which supports embedded NUL characters). Yet, there's only one byte-sized NUL terminator, instead of the two-byte sequence required in UTF-16, hence the trailing characters. Easiest solution would be to use `wifstream` and `wstring`.

Comment: @IInspectable yep I actually did try to use wifstream and wstring, it just gave me the first character of the first line, and the rest blank. Now I am starting to think that It might have something to do with how I created the file in the first place. The content(paths) were from IObjecWithSelection via shell extension,I escaped the backslash first before writing to the "file.tmp" and added "\r\n" also tried just "\n" for the next line. Now Im stuck..

Comment: You'd have to provide a hex dump of the file contents to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier expects a `const char*` (or `const wchar_t*`, depending on your character encoding settings), yet you are passing a `std::string` object. You need to invoke its [c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member:

```cpp
CStringA cs;
cs.Format("Reading: %s", s.c_str());

OutputDebugStringA(cs);
```

Or, when using Unicode character encoding (as you seem to be):

```
CStringW cs;
cs.Format(L"Reading: %S", s.c_str());

OutputDebugStringW(cs);
```

Note that the latter uses a Microsoft-specific extension, the format specifier type `%S`, that performs character encoding conversions between ANSI encoding and Unicode.